# Making element scroll-able is cutting off content

Tags: html, css, user-interface, scroll, bulma

I am developing a web-application which frequently uses tooltips. The application is styled using the [Bulma CSS library](https://bulma.io/) along with the [Bulma Tooltip Extension](https://wikiki.github.io/elements/tooltip/). Some elements in my application have internal scrolling (with their overflow-y property set to 'scroll' or 'auto'). Setting overflow-y to 'scroll'/'auto' automatically sets overflow-x to 'hidden (this is inevitable according to other answers).

**This is causing overhanging tooltips to be cut off, as can be seen in this sandbox:**

While I understand that having a visible x overflow with a scroll-able y overflow is impossible, I imagine that there is some work around/solution that will allow at least allow for the appearance of displaying an overhanging tooltip in a scroll-able element. In my case, allowing for visible overhang on the x-axis is more important (no other question/answers address/resolve this exact issue).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```css
#testDiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 75px;
  overflow-y: auto; /* Delete Line to see full tooltip */
}

.button {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.2/css/bulma.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://wikiki.github.io/css/documentation.css?v=201904261505">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="testDiv">
      <button class="button tooltip" data-tooltip="This is a Tooltip">X</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another `div` element (`.wrapper`) that will have default overflow settings. It will be a container for your `#testDiv` and `.button`.

Now, Add `position: relative` to `.wrapper`.
`.button` now can be positioned absolutely, to just look like it's inside `#testDiv` element, but technically - it isn't :)

`#testDiv` element need to be expanded to 100% width and height, to inherit size from `.wrapper`

Last step - add some padding-top to `#testDiv` to prevent content overlap on `.button` element.

Look at code below:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 75px;
}

#testDiv {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-y: auto; /* Delete Line to see full tooltip */
}

.button.tooltip {
  margin: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.2/css/bulma.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://wikiki.github.io/css/documentation.css?v=201904261505">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <button class="button tooltip" data-tooltip="This is a Tooltip">X</button>
      <div id="testDiv">
        content
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I hope this solution will suffice :)

Comment: Acceptable, but wondering if there is a more simple solution...

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
}
```